# django was_published_recently error

Tags: django

In tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/) I get down to where you run was_published_recently and I get this error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/polls/poll/
>   PollAdmin.list_display[2], 'was_published_recently' is not a callable or an attribute of 'PollAdmin' or found in the model 'Poll'.
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    /admin/polls/poll/
>   Django Version: 1.4
>   Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
>   Exception Value:
>   PollAdmin.list_display[2], 'was_published_recently' is not a callable or an attribute of 'PollAdmin' or found in the model 'Poll'.
>   Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\validation.py in validate, line 38

here is my code:

```
from polls.models import Poll

from django.contrib import admin

from polls.models import Choice

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Choice
  extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   fieldsets = [
    (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
   inlines = [ChoiceInline]

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   # ...
   list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')

  admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

here is my poll model

```
  from django.db import models

  class Poll(models.Model):
   question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


  class Choice(models.Model):
   poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
   choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   votes = models.IntegerField()

  class Poll(models.Model):
   # ...
   def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question

  class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.choice
```

Comment: If you go down the stack, which line from your code raises the error?

Comment: Hey, I am getting the following:    File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\datetime.py", line 1765, in _datetime__cmp
    raise TypeError("cannot compare naive and aware datetimes")
TypeError: cannot compare naive and aware datetimes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you update your question with your `Poll` model?

It looks like you may have made a mistake when adding the `was_published_recently` method to your `Poll` model in the [Playing with the API step](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#s-playing-with-the-api) in Tutorial 1.

## Update:

Now that you've posted your model, it does look as if you've missed out the `was_published_recently` method. Go back over tutorial 1 and add it in.

Secondly, don't include each model more than once in models.py - the second one will replace the first.

Comment: No problem! Please click the tick to show that your question has been answered.